# Main text overlapping over footer

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my main content texts overlapping in front of my footer. So far, I got the footer to stay at the bottom but when I type longer descriptions filling the entire page so you can scroll, the footer is right underneath the text at the bottom with the content texts overlapping.

How do I fully keep it at the bottom without the main content texts (or images) overlapping over the footer?

```css
.grid{
    min-height: 92vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) { 
    body { 

       font-size: 90%;
    } 
    
    footer {
        h1 {
          flex: 1;
        }
    }

} 

.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: -30px;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: -30px;
}

footer {
    min-height: 1vh;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 85%;
        li{
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }
}

.copyright {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
        <div class="title"><h1>Title</h1></div>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <p>Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam.</p>
            <p>Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus.</p>
            <p>Egestas sed sed risus pretium. Lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus.</p>
            <p>Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Et netus et malesuada fames ac.</p>
            <p>Ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare. Lacus sed viverra tellus in. Sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas.</p>
            <p>Purus in mollis nunc sed. Sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque.</p>
            <p>Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <div class="copyright">2020</div>
            <li class="link"><a href="link">link 1</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="link">link 2</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="link">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
```

Solution:

Removed `bottom: -30px` and `position: relative` from `.text` class. Add `margin-top: 30px` to `<footer>` element.

Keeps the footer below, while the content text does not overlap.
Also remove `.title` class, and fit it under `<div class="text">` instead so the main content text doesn't overlap.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Remove the position: relative property, added for class text, Check if that's how you want it..

Comment: Also, bottom: -30px property becomes obsolete, if you decided to not use position: relative

Comment: I removed 'position: relative' for the class 'text', but it does nothing. The content text is still overlapping the footer.

Comment: Remove the ``bottom: -30px`` property on your ``.text`` class and you're good to go. Furthermore, you can add ``margin-top: 30px`` property on your ``footer`` element. That way it will be quite better and separated your main text from the footer.

Comment: Okay, I removed `bottom: -30px` and `position: relative` from `.text` class. The content text doesn't overlap the footer anymore but it does overlap title but I can rearrange the title to fit it within the content text. I have also added `margin-top: 30px` on the footer element, that solved the additional texts I've added which now displays when I scroll. Thank you so much for the fast response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a css property of padding-bottom: 1vh (exact height of the footer) to your div with the class of grid.

This way the .grid container will not cover the full page but leave space of 1vh at the bottom, thus not overlapping your footer.